# Is Microsoft's botframework free of cost?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I made an application in Microsoft's bot framework and hosted it online using azure bot channel registration, however, later I found out that only 10000 msgs/month are alotted according to the free plan, and the other one costs a huge $0.5 per 1000 messages which is quite expensive if many customers are going to use it at a time. So is there any other way to create a bot channel free of cost (after the last update?, because there was a way before, but since Microsoft changed its policy from March 18' it seems we'll have to at least register the bot for channeling which will cost further after your one month trial is over).

I want to have a plan of unlimited requests free of cost, so any other alternatives to bot framework? Also, if there is none, can we build the bot with our own built UI and Get/Post requests, etc and construct it into a web Api? Any tutorials for such task which could help me?

I've already hosted the bot on IIS server, all I'm looking for is a channel so that I can embed my bot on other websites.

Comment: It's freemium, AFAIK all things are limited (in free) (once your app use more than allowed Quota, you need to pay)

Comment: Do you want to host you bot on a Public website, which is accessible over internet? And you mentioned that the bot is hosted on IIS, so it a dedicated server server?

Comment: I know, I want to know whether there's an alternative to bot framework. I actually found one called bot.ai which is free for unlimited messages but has limited features and no form flow. Hence, anything with both the pros? Else, any tutorial where I can build the framework on my own? Like basic get/post requests plus how to create the chat UI and display bot's message and user post differentially, etc?

Comment: Yes @HariGovind, I can access my bot, but I guess without a channel I can't really use my bot. Refer to my previous question here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480422/c-sharp-bot-framework-resource-not-found-error

Comment: I have worked with MS Bot Framework and its implementation for over an year now...and we have deployed various solutions as well, if need any further help you can send me a direct message and we can chat there...and lets not spam here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Azure Bot Service if you want to use premium channels then the limit is 10000 messages/month there is simply no workaround to this.

But its not to say that its impossible, there is a Node.js module available called **Offline Directline**, this lets you emulate Directline Channel but on a server. So in theory you have this hosted server and then **try to connect to Offline Directline channel instead of MS Bot Framework**.

But this is not an easy thing to crack and would take significant amount of development efforts, as things like managing history of messages in a conversation and its management such as clean up to free memory has to be done manually. Me and team had developed a similar solution, to run Bot completely offline inside a local intranet.

You can find more details about Offline Directline here: [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline)

Answer (score 3):

The Azure Bot Service has now been [Generally Available](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Azure+Bot+Service+GA&oq=Azure+Bot+Service+GA&aqs=chrome..69i57.2800j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which means they're providing a paid service with incurring subscription cost. The free tier, as you mentioned above, is capped at 10000 msgs/month. The previous Preview (or Beta) did provide the channels for free although they don't guarantee the SLA.

There might be a way to build a bot on top of MS BotFramework SDK and modify the library to create a channel emulating the [bot emulator](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=bot+emulator&oq=bot+emulator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1671j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in your local server without connecting to DirectLine API. But it might require significant development to emulate it.

If you're looking for another SDK, [Botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit) is a popular choice among developers. It has a bunch of middleware available for popular messaging platform i.e. FB Messenger, Slack, etc.

Comment: "But it might require significant development to emulate it." 
Any github example or article that may help for this approach.

Comment: @user8321763 as Hari Govind pointed out above, you can check [Offline Directline](https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline_dl) module. You can also check the official [bot emulator](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=bot+emulator&oq=bot+emulator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1671j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) repo to check on how the call is done from the client side and try to emulate it.

Comment: It seems even botkit costs money once I deploy it for business purpose. $99.0/month for max API calls, and 10000 active users :/

Comment: @user8321763 the sdk itself is free and you can use it to create a bot and host it in your own server. Botkit-studio on the other hand is a paid service provided by that company. However, with the free open source library, you're already able to build a bot.

Comment: I created a sample application on botkit, but it's requesting studio token every time and throws an error if not provided. Isn't there any workaround to run without a studio account, because account costs money as I told earlier?